# Ubuntu 12.04 won't boot on Samsung Series 9 NP900X3A (ssd hard-drive)

Tags: 12.04, ssd, samsung

I've recently bought the [Samsung Series 9 NP900X3A](http://www.samsung.com/us/computer/laptops/NP900X3A-A03US-specs)
I boot the live usb ubuntu 12.04 and format the ssd drive. I then created 2 partitions: 28GB for / and 100GB for /home

After install I reboot the laptop. It seams that on boot the screen blicks and restarts again.
I've also made the regular Ubuntu 12.04 install without any luck.

Any idea?

Comment: Are you booting with the USB drive in? I believe Ubuntu 12.04 for some odd reason installs GRUB to the USB drive by default. It might be that the computer can't find the bootloader on the HDD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look wether it could [depend on uefi](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1969571).

I just got this fixed for myself by disabling uefi explicitly in bios. I'm pretty sure that this could help you.

Good luck!

Comment: While partitioning, did you select your master drive in "Device for boot loader Installation"?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you were able to resolve your issue, but I ran into an similar issue and was able to resolve by disabling Fast BIOS Mode to allow boot from USB to do a boot recovery.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are missing a pointer in grub2 that tells the pc to load the ubuntu 12.04 you put onto your Samsung Series 9 NP900X3A, or missing a grub2 install completely. I run into the same problem when installing ubuntu 10.04, 11.04, 11.10, and 12.04 on my Samsung Series 9 NP900X3A. I used the following sites to help me install grub from the USB-live drive which was used to install ubuntu in the first place:

[Grub2 man](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2)
[Grub2 Repair](http://www.ohbuntu.blogspot.com/2009/11/repair-grub2-after-install-windows-7.html)

Answer (score 0):

It works fine with a UbuntuMini.iso (I downloaded a server iso).

I have created the USB boot image with Lili USB creator. Took time to download the whole thing over my wifi, but it works. Installed Ubiquity.

Bluetooth mouse Logitech M555b working.

14GiB for / and 4GiB for swap.

Comment: with an SSD you dont need the swap partition