# Ubuntu will not boot after upgrade

Tags: boot, grub2, upgrade

I upgraded from 10.04 to the next version and now I see the Ubuntu logo briefly and the screen goes blank. I can get to the recovery mode. How can I fix this problem without losing the existing data?

Comment: 10.04 then. I apreciate specific help instead of a reference to a previous question that's not helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to make a boot repair. For that refer the following link:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: The problem is I cannot boot from USB. I have Samsung laptop and I could not figure out how to change BIOS to boot from USB.http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/show/40334-booting-modern-samsung-laptop-from-usb-drive

Comment: Try watching the following video:     http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RJJ7C_m9Eaw

Comment: Try reading the video comments also.

Comment: Thanks. This was helpful. I changed the setup as instructed but it still goes to GRUB screen instead of booting from USB.

Comment: Have you disabled the Fast boot option in the BIOS?

Comment: I am at the command line now. Is there a way i can boot from USB from the command line?

Comment: No. Commannd prompt won't help. What is your laptop series and model?

Comment: I have "Fast BIOS Mode" Disabled under Advanced tab in BIOS

Comment: Then try booting now.

Comment: Samsung NP275E5E-K01US

Comment: May this help you :http://askubuntu.com/questions/208022/unable-to-boot-from-a-usb-drive-on-samsung-series-9-notebook

Comment: I try booting but it still goes to black screen or GRUB screen

Comment: Ok I ran the boot repair but did not fix the problem. I guess I will ask the question in ubuntu forums and hope that the guy who wrote it will reply. Is this correct? Thanks for your help.