# Installation from usb option doesn't show up when I restart

Tags: 14.04

I am trying to install Ubuntu 14.04.4 from my usb following the instructions in http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop . I downloaded it and put it my usb. But when I restart my computer, I do not get a "welcome screen prompting you to choose your language and giving you the option to install Ubuntu or try it from the USB".

I tried to press F12, but it does not work.

Any idea?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you changed the boot order in BIOS to boot from USB or while restarting Windows? Also is secureBoot turned off in BIOS?

Comment: I just checked, and USB is the first in the priority list. Still it does not show anything.

Comment: Please check your .iso image and the USB drive...you can try that in another computer if needed.

Comment: Did you ever startet your computer from a usb-stick? If not, did you check the BIOS if usb-storage ist activated? Can you select the BIOS-boot menu on system start? What kind of computer / mainboard do you have?

Comment: When you say you downloaded it and put it on your USB, do you mean you copied the ISO file itself to the drive?

Comment: @Ashu I downloaded ubuntu-14.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso from www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop . Then I put it into an empty usb. I guess this is the rigth thing to do?

Comment: @cmks I never did. I do not know how to check if the usb-storage is activated. I can select BIOS-boot menu on start and I checked USB is the first in the priority list. I have a SAMSUNG 900X.

Comment: @Zacharee1 yes indeed. I copied ubuntu-14.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso to my usb. I downloaded it from  www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop. Isn't this the right thing to do?

Comment: @Mencia No, you need to use a program such as Unetbootin to extract and burn the files inside the ISO to the USB stick.

Comment: What program should I use in a mac? @Zacharee1

Comment: @Mencia I believe Unetbootin is cross-perform

Comment: please refer http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu for a complete guide on installing ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## First you need to create Bootable usb

1. Download Ubuntu Desktop
2. Open the Terminal (in /Applications/Utilities/ or query Terminal in Spotlight).
3. Convert the .iso file to .img using the convert option of hdiutil e.g.,

   ```
   $ hdiutil convert -format UDRW -o ~/path/to/target.img ~/path/to/ubuntu.iso
   ```

   Note: OS X tends to put the .dmg ending on the output file automatically.
4. Run

   ```
   diskutil list
   ```

   to get the current list of devices.
5. Insert your flash media.
6. Run

   ```
   diskutil list
   ```

   again and determine the device node assigned to your flash media (e.g. /dev/disk2).
7. Run

   ```
   diskutil unmountDisk /dev/diskN
   ```

   (replace N with the disk number from the last command; in the previous example, N would be 2).
8. Execute

   ```
   sudo dd if=/path/to/downloaded.img of=/dev/rdiskN bs=1m
   ```

   (replace /path/to/downloaded.img with the path where the image file is located; for example, ./ubuntu.img or ./ubuntu.dmg).
   Using /dev/rdisk instead of /dev/disk may be faster
   If you see the error dd: Invalid number '1m', you are using GNU dd. Use the same command but replace bs=1m with bs=1M
   If you see the error dd: /dev/diskN: Resource busy, make sure the disk is not in use. Start the 'Disk Utility.app' and unmount (don't eject) the drive. Also be aware that you won't be able to see the progress of image creation and it may take up to an hour sometimes.
9. Run

   ```
   diskutil eject /dev/diskN
   ```

   and remove your flash media when the command completes.
   10
   Restart your Mac and press alt/option key while the Mac is restarting to choose the USB stick.

Instructions taken from official docs [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx).

Also check that you can choose which device you want to boot from from boot menu (do not change the default instead use something like F12 to choose the device) this will depend on the model of pc.

Comment: Your answer might be helpful, but please note that OP don't have an Ubuntu already installed. So he cant open terminal.

Comment: If you read the comments question was how to do it on mac. And this instructions are for Mac. In Ubuntu you wouldn't have to convert .iso to .img aš well.

Comment: @T.Chmelevskij thanks! After I did step 8, my computer complained: "The disk you inserted was not readable by this computer." Then it gives me the option to: Initialize..., Ignore or Eject. What should I do?

Comment: Also, in step 8 I did "if=/path/to/downloaded.img.dmg" instead of "if=/path/to/downloaded.img", because as you said, OSX adds .dmg at the end after step 2.

Comment: It's fine this means it was created successfully. Now just try to boot from it and it should work

Comment: Also what's the laptops model you want to install Ubuntu on?

Comment: @T.Chmelevskij should I choose eject then? My laptop is a Samsung 900X.

Comment: @T.Chmelevskij or Ignore?

Comment: @Mencia You need to eject it. Your laptop uses UEFI so it a bit more complicated. But it was done and you can search for it yourself. One of the questions [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/208022/unable-to-boot-from-a-usb-drive-on-samsung-series-9-notebook) has an answer and some useful links. Also please don't flood the comments with questions as your last and show some effort of doing research yourself by using search engine of your choice. Thank you.